# I want to use get_attribute in a value but don't have 'data_value' just number, How can I get the information using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I'm using in my code the library Selenium in Python, but I can't get the value in a page with inspect google.

```
primeiro_value = nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/ng-view/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div').get_attribute()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: use `class` insitead all these `div`

Comment: how about `.text` like `nav.find_element_by_xpath(...).text` ? better find some tutorial because it is basic knowledge.

Comment: Try with `.text` or `.get_attribute("innerText")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.get_attribute()` without any attribute.

If your sole purpose is to get `240.558` and this xpath `/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/ng-view/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div` represent the `div` which has that **numric value**, you could do the following to get the value

```
primeiro_value = nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/ng-view/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(primeiro_value)
```

or

```
primeiro_value = nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/ng-view/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div').get_attribute('innerText')
    print(primeiro_value)
```

or

```
primeiro_value = nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/ng-view/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div').text
    print(primeiro_value)
```